# worst case in terms of performance with PHP if else statement

Tags: php

```
function quadrant($x,$y) {

if( $x >= 0 && $y >= 0 )
    $result = "point ($x,$y) lies in the First quandrant";
else if( $x < 0 && $y >= 0)
    $result = "point ($x,$y) lies in the Second quandrant";
else if( $x < 0 && $y < 0)
    $result = "point ($x,$y) lies in the Third quandrant";
else if( $x >= 0 && $y < 0)
    $result = "point ($x,$y) lies in the Fourth quandrant";

return $result;

}

$x=1;
$y=1;
$q = quadrant($x,$y);
```

what is the value of $x or $y that is the worst case in terms of performance? and how many comparisons are made?

what is the value of $x or $y that is the best case in terms of performance? and how many comparisons are made?

Comment: How many times do you need to run this function? If it's less than tens of thousands of times, the difference is going to be negligeable.(Also the most reliable way to find this out is probably to test it yourself, with the different cases that you have)

Comment: Need more information. You question seems incomplete.

Comment: The question has probably been asked by his teacher

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is simply a matter of counting.

Best case: x and y both non-negative. 2 comparisons (`$x >= 0` and `$y >= 0`).

Worst case: x non-negative and y negative. 6 comparisons. That's because php stops at the `&&` if the first statement is already `false` since the result can't possibly be `true` no matter what the second statement returns. Thus, the second and third `if` will already stop evaluating after `$x<0` is evaluated to false.
Also, the last `if` is totally unnecessary and just adds 2 comparisons in the "worst" case. Removing it and leaving just the `else` will get this case down to 4 and make "x and y both negative" the worst case with 5 comparisons.

Here's a more efficient version:

```
function quadrant($x,$y) {

    if( $x >= 0 ) {
        if( $y >= 0)
            return "point ($x,$y) lies in the First quandrant";
        else
            return "point ($x,$y) lies in the Fourth quandrant";
    }
    else if( $y >= 0)
        return "point ($x,$y) lies in the Second quandrant";
    else
        return "point ($x,$y) lies in the Third quandrant";

}
```

This has always 2 comparisons.

Comment: kudos for understanding the question. I didnt :)

Comment: For the provided code, it's 8 (even if the last `else if` can be replaced by a simple "else" .

Comment: @Asenar: php stops at the `&&` if the first statement is already `false` since the result can't possibly be `true` no matter what the second statement returns. Thus, the second and third `if` will already stop evaluating after `$x<0` is evaluated to `false`. If you plug in the different possible combinations of $x and $y, you get 2, 3, 5 and 6 comparisons thanks to this feature.

Comment: @Asenar: This also means if he indeed removed the last `if` and left just the `else`, the worst case would become 5. By the way, this feature is commonly used to shorten branches: `someBoolean && trueFunction();` is equivalent to `if (someBoolean) trueFunction();`, while `someBoolean || falseFunction();` is equivalent to `if (!someBoolean) falseFunction();`, the latter being used mainly to catch "errors", where some function simply returns false when something goes wrong and leaves error handling to the programmer.

Comment: you're right I'm sorry, I forgot the fact than only the first conditions is checked. I suggest you to add this in your answer ;)